# Create C# universal app error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, win-universal-app

When I tried to create a blank C# universal app project in VS2013, it reports the following consecutive errors

Says: A problem was encountered creating the sub project'App1.Shared'. The composition produced a single composition error. The root cause is provided below. Review the CompositionException.Errors property for more detailed information.

1) No exports were found that match the constraint....

[image: Error 1]
[image: Error 2]
[image: Error 3]

And then what's really created is just this

[image: What's left]

PS. works fine when creating C++ universal app project, or when I create a WP8.1 project or a Windows 8.1 project, it's just the universal app. Can anyone help?

Comment: I see an ideogram in folder path. Maybe that's the problem. Try again, but on path with only ASCII characters.

Comment: This has never been the problem, I tried again and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Try loading vs2013 in safe mode - use this command devenv.exe /safemode and let me know if that works for you. it may point for some problems in vs extensions.

Comment: No it didn't work, the error's still the same

Comment: Also try `devenv /setup` from an elevated command prompt.